# Adding "bServerSide": true in datatable giving error TypeError: g is null

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, datatables

I am working in JavaScript and Java. Using jQuery DataTables, there is error while I add `"bServerSide": true` in data table.

> TypeError: g is null
>
> ...ata?a.fnServerData.call(j,a.sAjaxSource,h.map(b,function(a,b){return{name:b,valu...
>
> jquery....min.js (line 33)
>
> TypeError: c is undefined

After adding  `"sAjaxSource"` it gives another error:

> i[n] is undefined

The jQuery code is below.

```
 table2 = $('#table2').dataTable(
            {
                "info": false,
                "bLengthChange": false,
                "bFilter": true,
                "bServerSide" : true,
                "oLanguage": {"sSearch": ""},
                responsive: true,
                "paging": false,
               "sAjaxSource" : basePath+'/secure/bartender/list.json',
                "aoColumns" : [
                        {
                            "mData" : "srNo",
                            "bVisible":true 
                        }, 
                        {
                            "mData" : "craftBeerName",
                            "bVisible":true 
                        }, 
                        {
                            "mData" : "tapStatus",
                            "bVisible":true 
                        }, 
                        {
                            "mData" : "action",
                            "bSortable":false 
                        }

                ],


                "fnServerData" : function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
                $.ajax({
                "dataType" : 'json',
                "type" : "GET",
                "url" : sSource,
                "data" : aoData,
                "success" : fnCallback
                });
                },
                "sPaginationType" : "full_numbers"
//                "iDisplayLength": 2
            });
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Can you provide the fiddle for same or you can use normal jquery instead of minified so that you will come to know the exact error

Answer (score 0):

You have a missing comma after `"paging": false`.

Also make sure you have the same number of columns `<th></th>` in the `<thead>`/`<tfoot>` sections as you have in your data, you have defined `4` columns with `aoColumns`.